# Changing a specific line in a file with CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to record high scores for a game I am making. The idea is the scores are recorded, they are checked against the file for a matching username. If they match up and the score recorded is lower on the file then a new file is created, everything aside from the one line with the lower score is copied across then the current username and score is recorded. The old file is then deleted and the new one is renamed to match.

Unfortunately this does not seem to be working. The code seems to fail to copy across meaning I have to put another script in to make sure it does which then sometimes records incorrect results (lower) then reads them off wrong (readfile.[row]). Am I better off with another method or by pursuing this method further?

```
import csv, os, sys
def scorewriter():
replac = 0
writein = 1
string_score = str(score)
with open('highscores.txt','r') as csvfile:
    highscoresReader=csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in highscoresReader:
        for field in row:
            #recording high scores
            if field == username and string_score > row[1]:
                #MUST get to at least here
                     with open('highscores_temp.txt','a') as csvfiletemp:
                         highscoresWriter=csv.writer(csvfiletemp)
                         for row in highscoresReader:
                             for field in row:
                              #something wrong here, doesn't sort properly?
                                 if field == username:
                                     writein = 0
                                     replac=1

highscoresWriter.writerow([username,string_score])        
                                 else:

highscoresWriter.writerow([field,row[1]])

            elif field != username:
                continue

            elif field == username and string_score <= row[1]:
                writin = 0
                continue

if writein == 1:
    with open('highscores.txt','a') as csvfile:
        highscoresnewWriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        highscoresnewWriter.writerow([username,string_score])
if replac == 1:
    csvfile.close()
    csvfiletemp.close()
    os.remove(pathtofile)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems overly complicated. You'd be better off reading in all the data into a dict and then dealing with the logic of scores vs high scores once you've got that.

```
import csv

def write_score(hs_file_name, username, score):

    high_scores = dict()
    with open(hs_file_name) as hsfile:
        for row in csv.reader(hsfile):
            try:
                high_scores[row[0]] = row[1]
            except IndexError:
                pass

    if username not in high_scores:
        high_scores[username] = score
    elif high_scores[username] < score:
        high_scores[username] = score
    else:
        return False

    with open(hs_file_name, mode="w") as hsfile:
        writer = csv.writer(hsfile)
        for k, v in high_scores.items():
            writer.writerow([k, v])

    return True
```

Something like this, for example. You can even have it return True or False so that you can tell if this was a high scoring game. It's not necessary to do the temp file, it would be easier to just overwrite the old file.